# Change part of object color in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to change the color of some part of the object displayed on the scene. However, I'm unable to do it. I tried the code below :

```
        var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load('LFPL_IDRun01a_body.obj', 'LFPL_IDRun01a_body.mtl', function(object){
            object.position.set( 0, -90, 0 );
            object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

            object.traverse(function(child){
                if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                    child.material.color.setRGB(25,0,0);
                }
            });

            scene.add(object);
        }, onProgress, onError );
```

However, the object turns totally red. How can I change the color of the object without loosing the texture? Also, I only want some parts to be colored. I have another file with red parts that define areas where the color should be applied. How can I do that?

Edit :

Here is the whole code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="DDSLoader.js"></script>
<script src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="Detector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var PIXELRATIO = window.devicePixelRatio;

        var VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
        var ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
        var NEAR = 1;
        var FAR = 2000;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var container = document.getElementById('container');

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        camera.position.set( 0, 0, 200 );
        scene.add(camera);

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
        scene.add(ambient);

        var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
        directionalLight.position.set(0,0,1).normalize();
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        var onProgress = function(xhr){
            if(xhr.lengthComputable){
                var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
            }
        };

        var onError = function(xhr){};

        THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());

        var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
        loader.load('LFPL_IDRun01a_body.obj', 'LFPL_IDRun01a_body.mtl', function(object){
            object.position.set( 0, -90, 0 );
            object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

            object.traverse(function(child){
                if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                    child.material.color.setRGB(25,0,0);
                }
            });

            scene.add(object);
        }, onProgress, onError );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setPixelRatio(PIXELRATIO);
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        camera.lookAt(scene.position);

        animate();

        function animate(){
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        }

        function render(){
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: the code you have posted changes all the children of an object to color red. So you need another check which apparently you need to get from your other file but you don't provide any information on that.

Comment: I've edited my post. I put the whole code. Don't know if it's helpful or not.

Comment: now you are telling me "debug my code". your original question is not specific enough to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `traverse` argument to something like so:

```
object.traverse(function(child){
    if ((child instanceof THREE.Mesh)&&(part_needs_recoloring(child))) {
        child.material.color.setRGB(25,0,0);
    }
});
```

the specific test conditions of `part_needs_recoloring(child)` (which returns a boolean) I leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need add more condition! I alway add name of element i want add color

```
object.traverse(function(child){
    if (child.isMesh && child.name == 'like') {
        child.material.color.setRGB(25,0,0);
    }
});
```